# Is this guaranteed to overwrite %hash1 with %hash2 when conflict arises?

Tags: perl

```
%args = (%hash1,%hash2);
```

Is this guaranteed to overwrite `%hash1` with `%hash2` when conflict arises in Perl?

Answer (score 6):

Yes, it is.  Later keys overwrite earlier ones.

Comment: what about `{%hash1, %hash2}`?

Comment: & without () (&func instead of &func()) is a special kind of sub call that you probably don't mean to make.

Comment: what does &func() return?  and what's %args?

Comment: @Mike: other way around; Chas. wrote his answer in part in response to asker's comment here.

Comment: I "know" from experience that lists maintain their order, but I can't find this in the Perl docs. Out of curiosity, can someone point me to where this is documented?

Comment: @Mike Hashes do not maintain their order, though.

Comment: @TLP: I know, but by placing two hashes in a list, they *should* be processed in the order in which they are inserted - in the case of the question, the order of the keys in the hash shouldn't matter. I'm just curious about where the order of a list is documented. It's one of those things that just appears to be known. I've looked for documentation on this before, and not found it.

Comment: @Mike form [`perlglossary`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlglossary.html): "list: An ordered set of scalar values." and from [`perldata`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perldata.html): "LISTs do automatic interpolation of sublists. That is, when a LIST is evaluated, each element of the list is evaluated in list context, and the resulting list value is interpolated into LIST just as if each individual element were a member of LIST. Thus arrays and hashes lose their identity in a LIST" and "A hash can be initialized using a literal list holding pairs of items to be interpreted as a key and a value."

Comment: @Mike The practical upshot is that a hash in list context yields an list of key/value pairs. Once it is a list it has an order (the order it was returned in), you are never guaranteed what order the keys and values will come back in, but lists guarantee order of their elements, so `(a => 1, %h)` creates a list that starts with `"a"`, followed by `1`, followed by the first key returned by `%h`, followed by the first value returned by `%h`, and so on. That list is then assigned to the target hash in the list order, which means if the key `"a"` is in `%h` then it will override the original.

Comment: @Chas. Owens: Thanks. Yes, I understood that, and have used it many times in the past. I was going off-topic by asking about where in the docs it states that lists and arrays maintain their order - and you found it in the glossary. However, your explanation of why the list assignment technique works for merging hashes is probably the best answer on here - perhaps you should create it as an answer...

Answer (score 4):

If you aren't seeing overwriting behavior, then you are doing something wrong:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

sub func { print "func\n" }
sub tion { print "tion\n" }

my %args = (
    handler => \&tion,
);

my $dispatch = {
    handler => \&func,
    %args
};

$dispatch->{handler}();
```

From [`perldoc perlglossary`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlglossary.html#list):

- list
  An ordered set of scalar values.

From [`perldoc perldata`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perldata.html):

> LISTs do automatic interpolation of sublists. That is, when a LIST is evaluated, each element of the list is evaluated in list context, and the resulting list value is interpolated into LIST just as if each individual element were a member of LIST. Thus arrays and hashes lose their identity in a LIST

and

> A hash can be initialized using a literal list holding pairs of items to be interpreted as a key and a value.

The practical upshot is that a hash in list context yields an list of key/value pairs. Once it is a list it has an order (the order it was returned in), you are never guaranteed what order the keys and values will come back in, but lists guarantee order of their elements, so `(a => 1, %h)` creates a list that starts with `"a"`, followed by `1`, followed by the first key returned by `%h`, followed by the first value returned by `%h`, and so on. That list is then assigned to the target hash in the list order, which means if the key `"a"` is in `%h` then it will override the original.

Answer (score 0):

No. %hash1 is not modified at all by that statement.